# c# windows form - How received a tag value data into my textbox1?

Tags: regex, split, streamreader, htmlelements

```
<input name="chkFile" value="2062223616_7147073260_1440589192619132.WMA" type="checkbox">
```

from this code I want only the value data

Example:

```
2062223616_7147073260_1440589192619132.WMA
```

below my code not working so please help me.

My code

```
HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl)
            {
                if (bEl.GetAttribute("name").Equals("chkFile"))
                    showaudiourl.Text = bEl.OuterHtml.Split('"')[3];
            }
```

Comment: I am new in there so give me full details about regex solution.

Comment: Please write full code & show me then I am putting this in my coding & trying. I am new so please give me full details pls.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`webBrowser2.GetAttribute("value")`** to get the value you want.

```
HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl) {
    if (bEl.GetAttribute("name").Equals("chkFile")) {
        showaudiourl.Text = bEl.GetAttribute("value");    //Changes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is add a piece of code telling the app to wait until the web browser document gets initialized:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate(@"C:\tmp.html");                        // Use your own URL here
while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) // Without it, 
   Application.DoEvents();                                // the document will be null

HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl)
{
   if (bEl.GetAttribute("name").Equals("chkFile"))
      showaudiourl.Text = bEl.GetAttribute("value");
}
```

The value should be accessed with `bEl.GetAttribute("value")`.

Alternatively, you could use a `webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted` event to process the HTML document there.

Comment: And surely you do not need a regex. On SO, a lot of people would downvote your question if you ask to parse an HTML document with regex linking to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970) post.